# Nuendo Pitch Shift Plug-ins

Tags: plug-ins, nuendo

(Looking for a *non-factory* based graphical pitch shifter)

So it seems like Nuendo has a specific plug-in type that just does not exist for the DAW

Amazing pitch shifting plug-ins like pitch-n-time and the graphical soundshifter by waves do not work with Nuendo, forcing a scavenger hunt for some kind of pitch plug-in (graphical preferred).

Something like this would be great:

http://www.waves.com/Content.aspx?id=284

Waves Soundshifter does work with Nuendo, but only with limited functionality. Graphical mode is turned off.

The only workaround that I have seen thus far is just to bounce out any audio needed to be pitched graphically and use Sound Forge to do so.

Any ideas?

- C3

Comment: But Nuendo does come with it's own "graphical soundshifter"? http://d3vvl31cy8gagb.cloudfront.net/655_amen/10.JPG

Comment: @InternetHuman it does, but I am looking for an alternate. thanks though! ill edit my post

Comment: I've had no problems other than it using a ****load of CPU. What versions of Nuendo and Waves do you have?

Comment: @ChristianvanCaine Nuendo 5.5.3 -- the waves is fine, it just doesn't allow the graphical interface that I want.

Comment: @C3Sound Why not use Automation&PitchDriver and than use handy Export Mixdown (with checked option import into project). You will save resources and money.... OR you can use VariAudio (not so good for Sound Design) and AudioWarp for small Pitch and Time corrections in edit window.

Comment: @tomas-bilek Looking more along the lines of the waves interface that is comparable with the version available for pro tools but for nuendo. dunno why this doesnt exist.